# Is the text-link field broken in D7 views integration?

Tags: drupal-views

When creating a view in Drupal 7 to display CiviCRM activities (v 4.6) there is a text-link field available.

On selecting this field it can be configured to perform contact actions or activity actions (view, edit, delete) and set the link text as well as label.

I'd expect this to provide one of the text links we are all familiar with from the CiviCRM interface - however, when configured for activities, the result is that no data is displayed at all. There is no error message, the content is no longer displayed.

This happens regardless of the display settings (table, grid, calendar etc) for the view.

Is this field known to be broken, or should I persevere?

I have come across a similar problem before although this is marked as fixed in 4.6:

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15008

Answer (score 2):

I think the fix is in 4.7 - I have the same problem in 4.6.10.

There is a workaround - you can set any of the other fields as a link to the activity.

In your chosen field (I used the Activity Subject), go to 'Rewrite results' and select 'Output this field as a link'. In the Link path field, add:

civicrm/activity?action=view&reset=1&id=[id]&cid=!1

Then apply the change and save your view. This gives a link to the activity - if you want an edit link, try:

civicrm/activity/add?reset=1&atype=&action=update&reset=1&id=[id]&cid=!1&context=activity

Views will replace [id] with the activity ID and !1 with the contact ID

(If you want a text link separate from the other fields, add a Global custom text field and set it to rewrite as a link)